# My Simpe Hello World Console Application Exites With NONZERO EXIT CODE: 0xc000041d

Tags: c#, console-application

My friend is starting to learn C# using Visual Studio 2015 and I'm helping him.
After we wrote a simple hello world console application (below) it did not run at all.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Hi World");
    Console.ReadKey(false);
}
```

After I click the run button, it began to show diagnostic diagrams for a couple of seconds, but after that, exited the execution without showing console. I looked up at output window and I saw this error:

> The Program 'loblobloblob' Has Exited With Code -1073740771 (0xc000041d).

What might be the cause of this?

Comment: I'd create a new winforms project and do the classic "hello world" project if you're introducing him to c# and .net.

Comment: Capitalizing every word is very unnecessary..

Comment: Try running visual studio in Administrator mod and see if it helps.

Comment: @Wheels73 It Doesn't Help...

Comment: His original post said "And not make my mate hate C# and VS"... so i was simply suggesting what might be a more pleasant experience!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with the code you posted.

- Restart VS2015 (as regular user, no need for admin privileges)
- Create a new Console Application project. Name it "MyFirstProgram", or something reasonable

Ensure that your `Program.cs` looks as follows:

```
using System;

namespace MyFirstProgram
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");
            Console.ReadKey(false);
        }
    }
}
```

If this doesn't work, there is something wrong with your VS2015 installation.

Comment: I Restarted VS And It's Its Problem Was Solved. Thanks Alot